# What determines the maximum file size in ext2 file system

Tags: filesystems, ext2

I was reading the Kernel Documentation where it says

> There are various limits imposed by the on-disk layout of ext2.  Other
>   limits are imposed by the current implementation of the kernel code.
>   Many of the limits are determined at the time the filesystem is first
>   created, and depend upon the block size chosen.  The ratio of inodes
>   to data blocks is fixed at filesystem creation time, so the only way
>   to increase the number of inodes is to increase the size of the
>   filesystem.

For 4Kb block size, the file size is 2048GB.

I have also read that during data block allocation it uses direct, double or triple indirection to data blocks. Whether it is the main factor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2TiB file size is limited by the i_blocks value in the inode which indicates the number of 512-bytes sector rather than the actual number of ext2 blocks allocated.

Referenced from: http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html

Comment: This limit was also overcome ages ago by the use of a flag in the inode that indicates that the i_blocks value is, in fact, in units of block size rather than 512 bytes.  The triple indirect block structure though, can only address just over 4 TiB using a 4k block size.